# Hexadecimal input function calculates wrong values

Tags: c, input

I'm writing a function that can read integers expressed in hexadecimal.

This is my code. The `main` function should not be modified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 100

main()
{
    int array[SIZE], n;
    int gethex(int*);
    int i, sum;

    for (n = 0; n < SIZE && gethex(&array[n]) != EOF; n++)
        ;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    
    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
}


int gethex(int *pn)
{
    int c, sign;

    c = getchar();
    while (isspace(c))
        ;

    if (!isxdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '+' && c != '-') {
        ungetc(c, stdin); 
        return 0;
    }

    sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;

    if (c == '+' || c == '-')
        c = getchar();

    for (*pn = 0; isxdigit (c); c = getchar()) {

        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            *pn = 16 * *pn + (c - '0');
        }

        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
            *pn = 16 * *pn + (c - 'a' + 10);
        }

        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
            *pn = 16 * *pn + (c - 'A' + 10);
        }
    }
    *pn *= sign;

    if (c == EOF) {
        *pn = c;
        return c;
    }
}
```

The result value should come out like this.

```
-FFec
10000
^Z
The sum is 20
```

However, my code outputs

```
The sum is 1717986860
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your program, look at the variable values, and see where they deviate from what you would expect?

Comment: `while (isspace(c)) ;` will stall, as nothing is changed.

Comment: Aside: you can input in other number bases with `scanf("%i", &n);` and supplying data in the appropriate format. For example `42` (for decimal) `052` (leading 0 for octal) and `0x2A` (hex) all input the same value.

Comment: I don't know how to use debugging, so I used printf to check the value, and the array with -FFec and 10000 had the correct value, but it didn't end there and kept the strange value like -88989...  was in the array.

Comment: Can I not touch the main function even if we use scanf("%i", &n);?

Comment: "The main function should not be modified." Well, it can while you are developing. Keep it simple and just print the result of one input.

Comment: Since when is `main()` valid C?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, my compilation outputs `20` as expected, although I did reverse the positions of `main` and  `gethex` because you failed to provide a function declaration. But I get a compiler warning: *'gethex': not all control paths return a value*, and this must be fixed. Turn on compiler warnings and don't ignore them.

Comment: @WeatherVane The forward declaration is in the main function itself.

Comment: @sej I highly recommend you learn to use a debugger, since this will be valuable in your whole life as a programmer, not just for this assignment.

Comment: @JayK I see now. It's unconventional to do it like that , sej.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I suppose it is valid since the dawn of C. Without a return type declaration, int is assumed. Of course, nowadays it is unconventional to write it like this.

Comment: The compiler allows it for backward compatibility, but the conforming definition is `int main(void)`. Using `main()` is a sign that a student is using obsolete teaching resources.

Comment: I just checked it. I don't understand well because I'm not fluent in English, but I think the professor gave me a big task. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Also, you should set the warning level of your compiler to the maximum. This would hopefully elicit a message along *returning nothing from non-void function gethex()`*. Can you see where and under what condition?

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Warnings not fully enabled**

Warnings are not fully enabled, losing OP and others valuable time. [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631318/hexadecimal-input-function-calculates-wrong-values/70633526#comment124861001_70631318)

End of `gethex()` lacks a return value.

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

**Infinite loop**

Once a `'\n` is read, loop never ends. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631318/hexadecimal-input-function-calculates-wrong-values/70633526#comment124859719_70631318)

```
while (isspace(c))
    ;
```

Non hex input also set up an infinite loop with `ungetc(c, stdin);` as that same `c` will repeatedly get read on the next function call.

```
if (!isxdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '+' && c != '-') {
    ungetc(c, stdin); 
    return 0;
}
```

**`int` overflow possible**

Code like `*pn = 16 * *pn + (c - '0');` and `*pn *= sign;` can lead to `int` overflow, which is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Robust code would prevent that.

---

Some untested code to fix these issues.

```
// Return 0 if non-numeric input detected.
// Return 2 when input out of int range
// Return 1 on success
// Return EOF when input is only white-space, sign or none
int gethex(int *pn) {
  int ch;

  // Consume leading white-space
  do {
    ch = getchar();
  } while (isspace(ch));

  // Get sign, if any
  int sign = ch;  // remember 1st
  if (ch == '-' || ch != '+') {
    ch = getchar();
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    return EOF;
  }

  if (!isxdigit(ch)) {
    // Consume non-numeric input
    return 0;  
    // Perhaps better to return EOF here to stop calling code.
  }

  int overflow = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  while (isxdigit(ch)) {
    int digit = 0;
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      digit = ch - '0';
    } else if (isupper(ch)) {
      digit = ch - 'A' + 10;
    } else if (islower(ch)) {
      digit = ch - 'a' + 10;
    }
    if (sum <= INT_MIN / 16
        && (sum < INT_MIN / 16 || digit > -(INT_MIN % 16))) {
      overflow = 1;
      sum = INT_MIN;
    } else {
      // Accumulate as a negative number as there are more
      // negative vales than positive ones.  
      // This prevents bad code like -INT_MIN later. 
      sum = sum * 16 - digit;
    }
  }

  if (sign != '-') {
    if (sum < -INT_MAX) {
      overflow = 1;
      sum = INT_MAX;
    } else {
      sum = -sum;
    }
  }

  *pn = sum;
  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  return overflow ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Comment: sej, Hmmm, When non-numeric, non-whitespace input detected, I suggest to return EOF to stop the loop in `main()`.